# Connection error during image scraping from Craigslist

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, craigslist

As part of a project to scrape data from Craigslist, I include image scraping.  I've noticed in testing that sometimes the connection is refused.  Is there a way around this, or do I need to incorporate error catching for this in my code?  I recall the twitter API limits queries, so a sleep timer is incorporated.  Curious if I have the same situation with Craigslist.  See code and error below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#loops through each image and stores it in a local folder
for img in soup_test.select('a.thumb'):
    imgcount += 1
    filename = (pathname +  "/" + motoid + " - "+str(imgcount)+".jpg")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        response = requests.get(img['href'])
        f.write(response.content)
```

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='images.craigslist.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /00707_fbsCmug4hfR_600x450.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

I have 2 questions about this behavior.

1. Do CL servers have any rules or protocols such as blocking nth request within a certain time frame?
2. Is there a way to pause the loop after a connection has been denied?  Or do I just incorporate error catching so that it doesn't halt my program?

Comment: I find the error message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" to be clear. Are you asking what you can do to change the behavior of the Craigslist servers? Because regardless of what you do, at the end of the day the server gets to decide how to handle a request, whether by closing the connection, serving an error, or returning useful data.

Comment: I would assume that they probably have request rate limits. At the least add a delay between your requests and test if it improves matters.